# How Open a Dialog correctly in qt quick 2?

Tags: qt, dialog, qml, signals, qtquick2

I have a custom Dialog like below:

**CustomDialog.qml**

```
 Dialog{    
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("******* Loading Some Data from WebServcie ******")
    }
 }
```

Now I use this custom dialog in **main.qml** file:

```
 ApplicationWindow {
     id: mainWindow

        Button{
            id:btn
            onClicked: {
                cd.open();
            }
        }

    CustomDialog{
        id:cd
    }
}
```

When I run application,`Component.onCompleted` will executes,but I want this event execute after clicking the `Button` and after dialog will opend.How can I do this?

Comment: So you need [opened](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#opened-signal) or [aboutToShow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#aboutToShow-signal). or place your handler in btn.onClicked instead of useless `cd.open()`. If you can click the button that means that window is already visible.

Comment: @folibis I want to show dialog and then do some action.for example this dialog may be loading some data from webservice

Comment: Ok, what prevents you to do it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute some actions when your [`Dialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html) appears on the screen.

You can do that by checking if the [`visible`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html#visible-prop) property has changed :

**CustomDialog.qml**

```
Dialog {
  onVisibleChanged: { 
    if (visible) {
       console.log("I'm visible now !")
    } 
  }
}
```

Note that [`Component.onCompleted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal) is triggered when the component has been instantiated, not when the component is displayed to the user.